# document.write stops working when no data

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("property")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

When it gets no value, it stops working.
It's a for loop:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("object");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<table border='1'>");
  document.write("<tr><td>Last Communication</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("property")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

What should I do?

Comment: So check the value of `x[i].getElementsByTagName("property")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` before writting

Comment: for (i=0;i<=x.length;i++)

Comment: Don't use `document.write` like this. Best would be not to use `document.write` at all. It has multiple problems that are difficult to avoid, if you don't know what you are doing. In any case  **always** write complete elements (from opening to closing tag) at once, by putting everything in one string and use `document.write` once at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("object");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    document.write("<tr><td>Last Communication</td><td>");
    var item = x[i];
    if(item !== undefined) {
        var itemElements = item.getElementsByTagName("property");
        if(itemElements.length > 0) {
            if(itemElements[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
                document.write(itemElements[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue || '');
            }
        }
    }
  //...
}
```

Comment: every time you use an item array by index (`array[0]`) check for `array.length > 0`

Comment: also, as RoToRa wrote in question's comments. Don't use DOM objects in loops if posible. The better way is to create variable `var html = '';` and concatinate html content to it `for(var i = 0; i < array.lenth; i++) html += '<tag>..' + array[i].propertyName + '..</tag>';` and after loop and concatenation assign the value to DOM element by `document.write(html);` or `element.innerHtml = html;`

Comment: I tried it, any many options with it but none of them worked, actually what i need to do is write "Something" in the if statement if the node conains absolutely nothing

Comment: may you sholud check every potentially empty node with check `if(node !== undefined && node.propertyName !== undefined)`